# I am getting an error from django send_messages() AttributeError 'str' object has no attribute send_messages()

Tags: django

I have no idea where to start looking for the str in send_messages(); I believe my URL path isn't configured properly but I am not getting an ImproperlyConf Url error. I have attached the code for the view the URL and the template from which I am trying to send the email

#views.py

```
def email_invite(request):
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmailInviteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            name = f'{cd["name"]}'
            subject = f'{cd["name"]} has sent you a invitation'
            email = f'{cd["email"]}'
            to = [f'{cd["to"]}']
            comment = f'{cd["comment"]}'
            with open(str(settings.BASE_DIR.joinpath('templates/profiles/email/email_invite_message.txt'))) as f:
                invite_message = f.read()
            html_template = get_template('profiles/email/email_invite_message.html').render()
            msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, comment, invite_message, [email], [to], name)
            msg.attach_alternative(html_template, "text/html")
            msg.send()
            messages.success(request, 'Your email has been sent')
            return redirect('home')
            # return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profiles:find_friends'))
    else:
         form = EmailInviteForm()
    
    template = 'profiles/email_invite.html'
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

The URL that I think is the root of the error

#urls.py

```
  path('email-invite/', views.email_invite, name='email_invite'),
```

#email_invite.html

```
{% extends '_base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block extra_title %}Email an invite{% endblock extra_title %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <h1>Send a friend an invite to join you</h1>
    <p class="pages-p">
        Use the form to invite a friend or family member to sign up.

    </p>
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

The traceback error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/code/profiles/views.py", line 187, in email_invite
    msg.send()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 284, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])

Exception Type: AttributeError at /profiles/email-invite/
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'send_messages'
```

Any direction would be awesome. I have searched the docs and the net but I don't really understand the error message and when I put it into as search nothing comes up that is similar.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing wrong parameters to `EmailMultiAlternatives`. Like your code below

`msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, comment, invite_message, [email], [to], name)`

you are only allowed to pass these parameters

```
EmailMultiAlternatives(subject='', body='', from_email=None, to=None, bcc=None, connection=None, attachments=None, headers=None, alternatives=None, cc=None, reply_to=None)
```

Comment: Yes! Thank, you, when I removed the name variable, I got a bad header error because of new lines in the email_invite.txt; once I removed that also the email sent.